# how to in nested object get value from parent object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the material ui framework and create theme with `createMuiTheme`,  how to I can use the parent object values in nested object. *(I know I can define global variable above the function);*
for understand it better read the following code:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core";
import {grey, blueGrey, teal, red} from "@material-ui/core/colors";

export default createMuiTheme({

    palette: {
        common: {
            mainColor: blueGrey[500],
            headerColor: blueGrey[700],
            white: grey[50],
            black: grey[900],
        },
        primary: {
            main: palette.common.mainColor,  /* <= how to I can do this in Javascript */
        },
        secondary: {
            main: grey[300]
        },
        text: {
            primary: palette.common.white, /* <= or this */
            secondary: grey[500]
        },

    }

})
```

thanks.

Comment: look up how to use `this`

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**
But you can do this instead.

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core";
import {grey, blueGrey, teal, red} from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = {
  palette: {
    common: {
        mainColor: blueGrey[500],
        headerColor: blueGrey[700],
        white: grey[50],
        black: grey[900],
    },
    secondary: {
        main: grey[300]
    },
}

export default createMuiTheme({
  ...theme,
  palette: {
    ...theme.pallete,
    primary: {
        main: theme.palette.common.mainColor,  /* <= how to I can do this in Javascript */
    },
   text: {
        primary: theme.palette.common.white, /* <= or this */
        secondary: grey[500]
    }
  }
})
```